# iPad shows a wrong state of a website/app after app switch

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, web, redraw

I found nothing related to my problem, maybe I use the wrong keywords. But let me explain:

I have a strange problem with the iPad. We have a little javascript app/website, nothing special. It runs in a native app container via UIWebView. The problem is:

When we open a link (e.g. pdf) in an external safari window and switch back to the app (via four finger gesture or the button) sometimes (not always) we see an old state of the website (e.g. an old div container that should be hidden) until the iPad repaints the window (after a second or something). After the repaint everything is ok, but until this repaint we see something wrong.

We cannot rebuild the problem. It occurs somehow sometimes.

For me it looks like the iPad stores a screenshot of the website until it redraws the DOM, because it does not listen to any events. And sometimes the iPad stores a wrong screenshot?
Is this a known behavior of the iPad/Safari/UIWebView? Or is really a problem with some code in the app container or the website?

Answer (score 1):

I am using an iPad and iPhone sometime now with gestures, and this is something that got my attention as well. Even though I am not yet developing apps, I see this happening al the time.

Not only with uiWebView but also with apps like Spotify & TomTom. It always waits for a second or so and then repaints the app correctly, with sometimes an older state then it should have.

I guess this is how iOS works, and nothing really can be done about it.

Comment: Ok, I was afraid of it. But it is good to hear that other apps have the same problem.

Does anybody know if there is a documentation about this iOS-related things? (Sorry, I'm not an iOS-developer and I searched for something like a detailed technical documentation about iOS. But I guess there is nothing like this.)